# "Could" refers to possibility in both conditional sentence type 1 & 2

Tags: grammar

A speaker forecasts that it will rain tomorrow. He knows that the drainage system in his area is not good. He says with his friends:

> (1) If it rains tomorrow, it will flood.

A speaker knows that this season, it rarely has rain in his area, he doesn't think that it will rain tomorrow . He knows that the drainage system in his area is not good. He says with his friends:

> (2) If it rained tomorrow, it would flood.

==> "will" in conditional type 1 sentence changes into "would" in conditional type 2 with the same meaning which shows certainty in a real situation and in a hypothetical situation respectively.

But with the modal verb "could", "could" remains the same in conditional sentence type 1 and 2 to show possibility. Right?

> (1) If it rains tomorrow, it could flood (It will be possible to flood). (conditional sentence type 1)

> (2) If it rained tomorrow, it could flood (It would be possible to flood). (conditional sentence type 2)

Comment: Basically, yes. Note that this is not unique to "could"; "might", for example, could also be used in the apodosis of sentence 1 or sentence 2. Also, "can" is possible in sentence 1.

Answer (score 2):

The classification of conditional sentences into numbered "types" is not normally used by native speakers. It is a simplifying device used by ESL teachers, and **only** by such teachers. The numbered types capture the most commonly used conditional forms, but far from all valid forms. Many valid conditional sentences do not fit any of the numbered "types".

I advise against using this division of conditionals into types when communicating with a native speaker who is not familiar with ESL teaching methods. Many will have no idea what they mean.

The proposed sentences:

> (1) If it rains tomorrow, it will flood.

> (2) If it rained tomorrow, it would flood.

are both valid, and carry much the same meaning, the difference is small and subtle. Neither implies that the speaker is certain that it will rain tomorrow. Both imply that the speaker is reasonably certain that flooding would accompany any rain. Sentence (1) suggests that the speaker thinks that there is a significant likelihood of rain tomorrow. Sentence (2) suggests that the speaker is less convinced that there will be rain on the next day. Sentence (2) also suggests a greater possibility that rain could occur without flooding.

But this distinction is often not  carefully observed by fluent speakers. Many fluent speakers may treat (1) and (2) as interchangeable, and treat the suggested differences in meaning as unimportant.

> (3) If it rained tomorrow, it could flood.
> (4) If it rains tomorrow, it could flood.

Sentences (3) and (4) are also both grammatically valid and natural. A fluent speaker might use either. Sentence (3) suggests less assurance on the part of the speaker that flooding will following rain, if rain occurs, than sentence (2) does.  Sentence (4) makes the corresponding change to (1).

Again the distinction  between (3) and (4) may not be carefully noted by many fluent speakers. Indeed many speakers may treat all four sentences (1)-(4) as interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right.

Historically, *could*, *would*, *should*, and *might*, were the past tense of modals *can*, *will*, *shall*, and *may* respectively, and they are sometimes used in
this way:

> He said "they will come later" -> He said they would come later.

But in Modern English, they are also used as distinct modals, with their own meanings. When *could*, for example, is used in this way, it doesn't have a distinct past, and so doesn't change when backshifted.

> He said "Could you come on Thursday?" -> He asked if I could come on Thursday.

I've used examples of backshifting in reported speech, rather than conditionals, because it's clearer to see what is going on; but the same applies in conditionals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help